Overwriting instance methods via multiple includes
Take the following code in ruby 3.3.0:
module A
  def print
    puts "A"
  end
end

module B
  def print
    puts "B"
  end
end

class C
end

c_instance = C.new

C.send(:include, A)
c_instance.print

C.send(:include, B)
c_instance.print

C.send(:include, A)
c_instance.print

I expected it to print out:
A
B
A

But it prints out
A
B
B

Why is that?

Note that C.send(:include, A) can be simplified to C.include A.

Ruby ignores the second call.
From Ruby docs:

Ruby's default implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to mod if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors. See also Module#include

This is a quote from append_features method description, which is used in include method

Yes, makes perfect sense, the moduke is already inside the ancestors chain. Thanks a lot!

It may not answer your question directly but you can use ancestors to check the final inheritance chain.
C.ancestors
# => [C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

There are numerous ways to have dynamic meta-programmings in Ruby. This time you were confused by :include, next time you may confused by :prepend or even other kinds of mysterious inheritance. You can even use
c_instance.method(:print).source_location

what the heck is inside that method
